# Jquery: small slideshow, how to create a var for the next slide to fade in over the top, and problem with setInterval

Tags: jquery, setinterval

http://jsfiddle.net/nicktheandroid/B7Rhe/5/

I'm trying to make the next slide fade in over the current slide, instead of fading all slides out before fading the next one in. I can't figure it out.

also, notice what i've commented out. I tried to make this a function, then call setInterval on the function, but it wasn't working, so I just setInterval around the function itself, instead of calling the function inside setinterval.

any help or recommendation is greatly appreciated.

```
var x = 2;
console.log('Not broken');

setInterval(function() {
// function slideshow() {
    var m = $('.slideshow li').size();
    x += 1;
    if (x > m) {
        x = 1;
    }
    $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
    $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(n)").animate({
        opacity: 0
    });
    $(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(" + (x) + ")").animate({
        opacity: 1
    });
// }
}, 2000);

//setInterval("slideshow()", 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is this:

```
$(".slideshow ul li:nth-child(n)")
```

`:nth-child(n)` just matches everything, passing n is the same as not including that selector at all.  So the problem is that you're fading out ALL of your elements and then fading the one back in.  You need to only fade out the visible one.  Change it to this:

```
$(".slideshow ul li:visible")
```

One other minor change.  On initial load you have all images shown so they will all hide.  You should hide all but the visible one on load so it works the first cycle.